# Call forwarding with twimlets in Django App

Tags: django, twilio, twilio-click-to-call

I am implementing a Twilio call functionality in my Django app, where in I want to get a call to specified no, after the call is picked by a person it should connect the call to another phone no.
This is what I have already implemented to get the call functionality running but I am not able to forward it to the desired no.

```
def call(country_code, to, lead_cc, lead_no, configuration):
account_sid = "XXX22a62f54bXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
auth_token = "XXXXXa61188eXXXXXXXXXXX"
client = Client(account_sid, auth_token)
no_str = str(country_code) + str(to[0])
no_uni = unicode(no_str)
lead_str = str(lead_cc) + str(lead_no[0])
lead_uni = unicode(lead_str)

client.calls.create(from_="+17xxXXXXX",
                               to=no_uni,
                               url= 'http://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber=+91xxxxxxxxx')
```

Also, I need pass "lead_uni" in the URL  like this but it's now working (url= 'http://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber=lead_uni').Please, sugges !

Answer (score 0):

It worked!  I am using Twilio Trial account so, I need to verify all the phone no used.
But passing the Variable 'lead_uni' in the twimlets URL is still not in place.

Comment: Not quite sure what you're trying to achieve with the url variable? Could you explain a bit more and what is working or not working? I'd love to help.

Comment: Thanks @philnash ,the issue is resolved .url='http://twimlets.com/forward?PhoneNumber='+lead_str      This is what need to be done.